# How to hide system folders in windows

Tags: windows

I have a computer with a clean Windows installation. I would like to hide all system folders on the C: drive: Program Files, Windows, Documents and Settings, etc. Basically, any folder on C: that I don't create myself, I want hidden. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's Vista32bit or XP, you could use Windows Steady State. It's a free tool designed for shared computer management. This can be done with local policy objects as well, but steady state makes it easy.

[image: SSScreenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the folder you want hide, click properties then a properties window will open. On the general tab, go to attributes click Hidden then apply, then your folder will be hidden

Comment: They are not hidden by default for a reason. While this is applicable in some situations, this is really not meant to be done on system files and folders. And if you do, do it to the folder and not to everything beneath that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Explorer
2. Go to Tools -> Folder Options
3. Click the View tab
4. Select "Don't show hidden files, folders or drives"
5. Select "Hide protected operating system files"
6. Click "Apply to Folders"
   [image]